# jQuery .on click event doesn't always fire on Ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I dynamically load contents. Inside the `$(document).ready` I have similar event handlers:

```
$(document).on("click", ".content_button", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // content
});
```

The problem is that the mouse click only recognised at around 90% of the clicks. It seems totally random. At other times I have to push the same button 4-5 times, and then it works. I have no error in the console, even the CSS part works every time:

```
div.content_button:active {
    top: 2px;
}
```

I can't seem to find a solution. I use jQuery 1.11, it works like this on Win10, Win7, inside Firefox, and even on iPad or Android.

Do you have any ideas about what can be the problem?

**Edit**:

`data.control` contains the `.content_button` divs (buttons) in HTML.

And here is the part, which loads the buttons:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:    'worker.php',
        async:  false,
        cache:  false,
        type:   "POST",
        data:   {   action:"update"   },
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
                    if(data.actionresult == 1)
                    {
                        $('div#container').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 500);
                        $('div#container').promise().done(function() {
                            $('div#container').html(data.control);
                            $('div#container').show();
                        });                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }
    });
```

Comment: I guess your observation is wrong. How do you check click event isn't fired?

Comment: Example in the content part there is an ajax call. I can see it in the developer console that: click - nothing, click - nothing, click - nothing, click - ajax call is happening. Also with another button I just show a div: I click the div, 90% of the times the div appear, but sometimes, I have to repeat the click. Also other users reported the same issue.

Comment: Provide all relevant code in question itself

Comment: An ajax request should never be a synchronous request and anyway this is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, I know, it will be fixed later.

Comment: Why later? It could explain why  the UI is not responsive. But on which context are you sending ajax request? On page load or what?

Comment: The UI is responsive as other buttons work, the CSS :active affect is visible, and also it wouldn't explain why it works perfectly almost every time. But I will try it - can't hurt. This ajax call is part of a function, which yes, runs also at page load, but it is also called at other times - like example when another ajax function finishes with success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the problem, it is this:

```
div.content_button:active {
    top: 2px;
}
```

On mouseDown it moves 2 pixels, so it is possible that the link won't be there after a mouseUp - so technically the click event won't fire as the mouseUp happens over another element.

I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".content_button").on("click",  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // content
});
});
```

It must be done like this.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be done like this. You aren't delegating event here. Maybe this could fix it regarding event bubbling if in some way click event propagation was stopped for any ancestor but then explain it

Comment: I think this won't work on a `.content_button` which you create after `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
$(function() {

   var count = 0;

   $('body').on('click', '.content_button', function() {
       count++;
       $('#count').html(count);
   });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/byexstpq/

Comment: You mean `$('body').on` instead of `$(document).on`? Then yes - same effect.